# indent of a list to the left

Tags: indentation

so my previous question got answered pretty well however I have some issues. I want to move the following list to the left(minor indent):

```
Let $G$ be a group, and let $G = \mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. 
Let $\chi:G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} = \{\mathbb{Z}\in\mathbb{C}:\lvert{\mathbb{Z}\rvert}=1\}$. 
Now we have: 
%
\begin{align*}
\chi\{0\} &= 1\\
\chi\{1\} &= a\\
\chi\{2\} &= a^2\\ 
\chi\{3\} &= a^3\\
\chi\{4\} &= a^4
\end{align*}

with $a = \exp\{\frac{2\pi\iu}{5}\}$ hence $a^5=1$.
```

I also want to put the last line of the 'code' in the same line as chi(2), as this looks more professional. also I don't want exp but the actual exponent as it looks much better.

Comment: I must point out, I started using latex today hence I am a novice.

Comment: I think it's better if the “with ...” line is just below the display. No blank line after `\end{align}`. Also an exponential notation in line is not really good and `\exp` is better, particularly with the fraction.

Comment: cheers. so to finalise, there's no need to change anything?

Comment: Just remove the blank line

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

A solution with the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`: it makes all display equations start at a fixed distance from the left margin (default `0pt`), like the `fleqn` option from `amsmath`, but only for the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, nccmath}

\newcommand{\iu}{\mathrm{i}}%

\begin{document}

Let $G$ be a group, and let $G = \mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.
Let $\chi:G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} = \{\mathbb{Z}\in\mathbb{C}:\lvert{\mathbb{Z}\rvert}=1\}$.
Now we have:
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{align*}
\chi\{0\} &= 1 &&\\% only need it once
\chi\{1\} &= a \\
\chi\{2\} &= a^2 \\
\chi\{3\} &= a^3 \\
\chi\{4\} &= a^4 \\
\intertext[1ex]{with $a = \exp\{\frac{2\pi\iu}{5}\}$ hence $a^5=1$.}
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{showframe}% dubugging tool

\newcommand{\iu}{\text{i}}% just a guess.  couldn't find definition

\begin{document}
Let $G$ be a group, and let $G = \mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. 
Let $\chi:G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} = \{\mathbb{Z}\in\mathbb{C}:\lvert{\mathbb{Z}\rvert}=1\}$. 
Now we have: 
\par% assuming \parskip=0pt
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\parindent}
\begin{flalign*}
\chi\{0\} &= 1 &&\\% only need it once
\chi\{1\} &= a \\
\chi\{2\} &= a^2  \\ 
\chi\{3\} &= a^3 \\
\chi\{4\} &= a^4 
\end{flalign*}
\hrule height0pt% a sort of horizontal strut
\end{minipage}
with $a = \exp\{\frac{2\pi\iu}{5}\}$ hence $a^5=1$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I offer a rather different way to typeset that math (and fix a few errors). If you want to get a professional look, then you should first of all not waste space. The rules for the function fit on one line. Don't repeat symbols:

> Let *G* be a group and let *G* = Z<sub>5</sub> = {0,1,2,3,4}

is wrong because *G* is not *a* group, as you're just defining a shorthand for a very specific group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\numberset{Z}}
\newcommand{\C}{\numberset{C}}
\newcommand{\T}{\numberset{T}}
\newcommand{\iu}{i}

\begin{document}

Consider the group $G = \Z_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and the \emph{circle group}
\begin{equation*}
\T = \{z\in\C:\lvert z\rvert=1\}.
\end{equation*}
Set $a = \exp(\frac{2\pi\iu}{5})$ and note that $a^5=1$. Define
$\chi\colon G \rightarrow \T$ by
\begin{equation*}
\chi\{0\} = 1,\quad
\chi\{1\} = a,\quad
\chi\{2\} = a^2,\quad
\chi\{3\} = a^3,\quad
\chi\{4\} = a^4.
\end{equation*}
It is easy to check that $\chi$ is a well defined map.

\end{document}
```

Note that you can define handy shortcuts for symbols you frequently use, that make the code easier to read and maintain.

[image]